# Initializing object using AOP

Tags: java, spring, reflection, javabeans, aop

Suppose I have several config classes as the ones below. All of them autowire a customObject which is configured based on a different filePath, and then its used to create another bean.

My concern with this approach is related to the fact that the customObject might need in the future another attribute (dependant on the config class) to work.

```
@Configuration
public ClassA{

    @Value("${A.filePath}")
    private String filePath;

    @Autowired
    private CustomObject customObject;

    @Bean
    public CustomObjectWrapper something(){
        customObject.set(filePath);

        return CustomObjectWrapperFactory.set(customObject).build();
    }


}

@Configuration
public ClassB{

    @Value("${B.filePath}")
    private String filePath;

    @Autowired
    private CustomObject customObject;

    @Bean
    public CustomObjectWrapper something(){
        customObject.set(filePath);

        return CustomObjectWrapperFactory.set(customObject).build();
    }


}

@Configuration
public ClassC{

    @Value("${C.filePath}")
    private String filePath;

    @Autowired
    private CustomObject customObject;

    @Bean
    public CustomObjectWrapper something(){
        customObject.set(filePath);

        return CustomObjectWrapperFactory.set(customObject).build();
    }


}
```

Reading a little bit about Annotations and AOP I was wondering if it's possible to create an annotation that ,after the config class has been instantiated, gets the instance of the config class and using reflection invokes every setter of every autowired attribute defined in it and passes to them the needed attributes based on their names.

The end result would be something like this:

```
@Configuration
@InstantiateAutowiredObjectsAfterCreation
public ClassA{

    @Value("${A.filePath}")
    private String filePath;

    @Autowired
    private CustomObject customObject;

    @Bean
    public CustomObjectWrapper something(){        
        return CustomObjectWrapperFactory.set(customObject).build();
    }


}
```

Comment: Definitely, absolutely _don't_ do that; it's complicated enough that I'm having a hard time understanding what you're even asking for. Spring can have several configuration objects; decompose your configuration. Even better, this smells like exactly the case that Spring Boot `@ConfigurationProperties` are meant for.

Comment: I don't think configuration properties will do any help here. At least per my understanding those doesn't work for custom types.

Comment: What do you mean "custom types"? Nearly everything in most Spring application is a "custom type" to one extent or another.

Comment: Suppose I create a new class annotated with @Component and @Scope("prototype"). Then in several config classes I autowire this component, and in every config class this component should be "initialized" with a filePath. This filePath is different in every config class. How would you use the ConfigurationProperties with this custom component.

Comment: It smells like you're using all the wrong abstractions here, but the answer to "how to force this to fit" is `Map<String, File>`. If the `CustomObject` varies per configuration class, it almost certainly shouldn't be a Spring bean, just a POJO you use inside the `@Bean` method, but it's hard to say in the excessively abstract.

Comment: Re read my original post. Every config class (A,B,C) needs one instance of CustomObject, which is a @component scoped to prototype. I'm almost sure that's the only way to adding a different filePath to every instance. What it would be the best way (using the correct abstractions), to set that filePath to that object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196679/discussion-between-chrylis-and-sebastianc).